# Debug Node/Express Application in intellij ultimate 2017.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, intellij-idea, node-inspector

I'm trying to debug my express application I have configured my IDE based on the intellij help documentation. But when I run the application, the process never stops at the break points.

Please find my configuration window details below: 
[image]

Intellij version :  2017.1
The bellow is what I'm seeing in the debugger console:

```
/Users/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.2/bin/node --inspect-
brk=64692 /Users/xxxxx/Documents/WORKSPACE/acme-
web/services/acme.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64692/453107ba-002c-4066-9b4c-
531e111aec87
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

My application runs on the port 8080.

Did I missed anything, any pointers would be helpful

**Edit :**

I have tried to use IJ-EAP-2017.2. This is giving me a new error in console while trying to debug.

```
/Users/user-xxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.2/bin/node --inspect-brk=55169 /Users/user-xxxx/Documents/WORK/acme-prj-web/src/common/pages/yyyyPage.js
Debugger listening on port 55169.
Debugger attached.
/Users/user-xxxx/Documents/WORK/acme-prj-web/src/common/pages/yyyyPage.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure why we are getting this error, still struggling to make the debugger work.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
```

Comment: does the error also appear when you run it normally with node? Without seeing the code we can't say what's wrong here.

Comment: This wont happen normally. I'm seeing this error only when I start the debugger. In the project we are using Babel, ES6 and webpack along with node/express

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console or in the module loader? Does your web app work as expected?

Comment: Yes, we are not seeing any errors in the web console. The application is working as expected. I'm seeing this error only when I try to debug in intellij.  Currently I'm using ultimate 2017.1 also I gave try with 2017.2-EAP

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem: `import` & `export` syntax of ES6 has still not yet been supported by Node.js. The current [**best proposal**](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es6-modules.md) is still on `draft` status unfortunately.

Some solutions you can use:

- Solution 1: Use [**Babel**](https://babeljs.io/) to enable full support for ES6 (and ES6+) syntax. Just follow [**the official installation guideline**](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) to get it done. You also need to use [**babel-node**](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node) to be able to debug ES6 full syntax.
- Solution 2 (recommended): Back to good-old-way by using `require & module.exports` (consider whether you **really need** `import / export`). And wait until Node.js officially releases full support for ES6.

Hope that this can help :)

Comment: Another solution would be use TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Please try 2017.2 EAP: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/. Some issues with Node 8 have been fixed since 2017.1.

Comment: I have tried the EAP without any luck. With EAP the debugger is exiting with code 1.

Comment: Does this means that I need to go for another IDE?

Comment: No. Just don't try to run client-side code with Node.js

Answer (score 0):

From the error message is seems that you are trying to run your React component with Node.js. 
React applications are normally executed by browser, this is a client-side code, so you have to build your application, start the server it is hosted on, and then debug it in browser using [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration.

Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/ for more information about debugging react apps